# Are algebras of smooth functions formally smooth?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, smooth-manifolds, smoothness, function-spaces

Let $M$ be a manifold. Then is the ring of smooth functions $C^\infty(M,\mathbb{R})$ [formally smooth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formally_smooth_map) over $\mathbb{R}$?

If it helps, feel free to assume that $M$ is compact.

---

(This is not a joke question. And yes, I know about $C^\infty$-rings and topological algebras, but I'm still interested in the above as stated.)

Comment: This is only a partial answer, maybe someone sees how to finish: for a point $x\in M$, we have the evaluation map $C^\infty(M)\to \mathbb{R}$. Its cotangent complex is really just $T^*_xM[1]$. To see this, we may localise to assume $M=\mathbb{R}^n$ with $x=0$, and then the kernel of the evaluation map is generated by the regular sequence of coordinates $x_1,..,x_n$. So from the conormal sequence we at least get that the base-changes of the cotangent complex $L_{C^\infty(M)/\mathbb{R}} $ along the evaluation maps are projective, given by $T_x^*M$.

Comment: (one would hope before basechange it is given by sections of $T^*M$, but I'm currently not sure whether we can detect this at the residue fields)

Comment: Is it formally smooth when $M=\mathbb N$, namely, what about the cotangent complex of ${\mathbb R}^{\mathbb N}$ over $\mathbb R$?

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that these comments are suggesting to employ Quillen's criterion that a ring map $A \to B$ is formally smooth iff $\Omega_{B/A}$ is projective and the cotangent complex is homotopy equivalent to it in degree zero? According to [this other question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/64498/formally-smooth-morphisms-the-cotangent-complex-and-an-extension-of-the-conorm), this also holds without finite presentation, right?

Comment: I believe that $k^I$ is not formally smooth over $k$ when $k$ is a field and $I$ is an infinite set.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: perhaps you can spell out the details in an answer? That would be helpful insofar as it would indicate that the question should be restricted to the compact case.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems $C^\infty(M;\mathbb{R})$ is not formally smooth for any positive-dimensional manifold. (The following argument came up in a discussion with Thomas Nikolaus, we later also found it [in this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/6074/kahler-differentials-and-ordinary-differentials/9723#9723)):

Let's start by discussing the case $M=\mathbb{R}$. Our strategy will be to show that $\Omega^1_{C^\infty(M;\mathbb{R})/\mathbb{R}}$ is not a projective $C^\infty(M;\mathbb{R})$-module. For a projective module $P$ over some ring $R$, different elements $x,x'\in P$ can always be separated by homomorphisms $P\to R$ (e.g. by embedding $P$ into a free module and using coordinate functions), equivalently the map $P\to P^{\vee\vee}$ into the double dual is injective. So it suffices to exhibit distinct elements of $\Omega^1_{C^\infty(M;\mathbb{R})/\mathbb{R}}$ which cannot be separated by homomorphisms to $C^\infty(M;\mathbb{R})$.

Claim 1: In $\Omega^1_{C^\infty(\mathbb{R};\mathbb{R})/\mathbb{R}}$, $de^x \neq e^x dx$. To detect this, it suffices to find a derivation $\partial: C^\infty(\mathbb{R};\mathbb{R})\to M$ with $\partial e^x \neq e^x \partial x$. Let $K$ be the fraction field of the local ring of stalks of smooth functions on $\mathbb{R}$ at $0$. Then $e^x$ and $x$ are algebraically independent in $K$,  so we may find a transcendence basis of $K$ over $\mathbb{R}$ consisting of $e^x$, $x$ and other elements $a_i$. It follows that $\Omega^1_{K/\mathbb{R}}$ is a free module on $de^x$, $dx$ and the $da_i$, in particular we find a derivation $K\to K$ taking $de^x$ to $1$ and $dx$ to $0$. Precomposing with the map $C^\infty(\mathbb{R};\mathbb{R})\to K$ yields the claim.

Claim 2: Every homomorphism $\Omega^1_{C^\infty(\mathbb{R};\mathbb{R})}\to C^\infty(\mathbb{R};\mathbb{R})$ takes $de^x$ and $e^x dx$ to the same element. Indeed, such homomorphisms correspond to derivations $C^\infty(\mathbb{R};\mathbb{R})\to C^\infty(\mathbb{R};\mathbb{R})$, which are given by smooth vector fields. But any smooth vector field $f\cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ takes $de^x$ to $f\cdot\frac{\partial}{\partial x} e^x$, and $e^x dx$ to $f\cdot e^x \frac{\partial}{\partial x} x$, which agree.

So $\Omega^1_{C^\infty(\mathbb{R};\mathbb{R})/\mathbb{R}}$ cannot be projective, and thus $C^\infty(\mathbb{R};\mathbb{R})$ is not formally smooth.

A zoomed-out version of the above argument is that the $C^\infty(M;\mathbb{R})$-linear dual of $\Omega^1_{C^\infty(M;\mathbb{R})/\mathbb{R}}$ is always vector fields, and so the double dual is always $1$-forms. Hence the above observation tells us that the map from "algebraic $1$-forms" $\Omega^1_{C^\infty(M;\mathbb{R})/\mathbb{R}}$ into its double dual identifies with the map to "smooth $1$-forms" $\Omega^1(M;\mathbb{R})$, and we have used algebraically independent functions with a linear dependence between their derivatives to show that map is not injective.

For $M=\mathbb{R}^n$, the same argument works for $de^{x_1}$ and $e^{x_1}dx_1$ with the coordinate function $x_1$. Finally, on a general manifold, take a coordinate ball around an arbitrary point, and extend the functions $e^{x_1}$, $x_1$ in any way. If $\psi$ is a function supported on our ball (and $1$ in a smaller neighbourhood of $x$), then we still have that $\psi \cdot d\widetilde{e^{x_1}}$ and $\psi\cdot \widetilde{e^{x_1}}d \widetilde{x_1}$ agree as "smooth $1$-forms", but not as "algebraic $1$-forms", as witnessed by going into the fraction field of stalks around our point.

EDIT: For a short proof that the stalks of $e^x$ and $x$ at $0$ are algebraically independent, first observe that since these are analytic functions, any polynomial relation $f(e^x,x)=0$ which holds in a neighbourhood of $0$ holds on all of $\mathbb{R}$, and in fact on all of $\mathbb{C}$. Since every nonzero $a$ is attained infinitely often as value of $e^x$, each of the polynomials $f(a,x)$ for fixed nonzero $a$ has infinitely many zeros in $x$, thus vanishes. So the coefficient polynomials in $f(y,x) = \sum g_i(y) x^i$ each have infinitely many zeros, thus vanish, and so $f=0$ as polynomial, proving algebraic independence.

EDIT2: In the zero-dimensional case, if $M$ is finite, $C^\infty(M;\mathbb{R})=\mathbb{R}^M$ is clearly formally smooth over $\mathbb{R}$. In the infinite case, they shouldn't be (following the comment by Martin Brandenburg). Indeed, a variant of the argument works. We still have that $C^\infty(M;\mathbb{R})$-valued derivations are vector fields, hence trivial. However, there exist nontrivial derivations on $\mathbb{R}^M$. Identify $M=\mathbb{N}$, fix a nonprincipal ultrafilter on $\mathbb{N}$, and let $K$ be the corresponding ultraproduct (which is automatically a field). The function $f: n\mapsto n$ is algebraically independent from $1$ in $K$, and so we find a derivation $K\to K$ taking $df$ to $1$. In particular, $df\neq 0$ in $\Omega^1_{\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}/\mathbb{R}}$. (If your manifolds are not second-countable, they still contain $\mathbb{N}$ as retract and you can still pull this nonzero element back.)

Comment: Thanks, that's beautiful and beautifully elementary!

Comment: What about the $0$-dimensional case? :-)

Comment: I think a variant of my argument works, replacing the fraction field of stalks by a suitable ultraproduct. I edited my answer with details.

Comment: I wonder whether the (algebraic) cotangent complex is concentrated in degree zero?